# Sails JS installation and database connection error

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I am new to **sails.js** and i am trying to make it work but unable to install it properly.

**During installation, first** it was giving **MSB4132 issue**
then i installed **visual studio 2010** to resolve that issue but then is starts showing around 2 pages of red text error. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

due to this issue sails new project is working fine but **when i am trying to connect it to my sql then it is showing  issue.**

**changes i made for connecting to mysql**

In **SailsTest/config/connection.js**

```
 TestServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    port: 4343,
    database: 'sailstest'
  },
```

In **SailsTest/config/model.js**

```
connection: 'TestServer',
migrate: 'safe'
```

In **SailsTest/api/controller/userController.js**

```
module.exports = {
    get:function(req, res){
        User.find()
            .exec(function(err, users){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    return res.json(err);
                }
                return res.json(users);
            })
    }
};
```

In **SailsTest/config/route.js**

```
  '/': {
    view: 'homepage'
  },
    '/user/get':'UserController.get'
```

after all this  on 
**http://localhost:1337/user/get** it is showing following error

```
{
  "error": "E_UNKNOWN",
  "status": 500,
  "summary": "Encountered an unexpected error",
  "raw": {}
}
```

**this is the error log coming.**

```
    Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
: Could not connect to MySQL:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4343
    at afterwards (C:\Users\Ashish\Desktop\SailsTest\node_modules\sails-mysql\lib\connections\spawn.js:72:13)
    at C:\Users\Ashish\Desktop\SailsTest\node_modules\sails-mysql\lib\connections\spawn.js:40:7
    at Handshake.onConnect (C:\Users\Ashish\Desktop\SailsTest\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:54:9)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (C:\Users\Ashish\Desktop\SailsTest\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:96:24)
    at Protocol.handleNetworkError (C:\Users\Ashish\Desktop\SailsTest\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:358:14)
    at PoolConnection.Connection._handleNetworkError (C:\Users\Ashish\Desktop\SailsTest\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:382:18)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1256:8)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:455:9)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:410:17)
```

Comment: 500 indicates internal server error. Check your webserver's error log for details.

Comment: yeah i know that it is server connection issue but didn't able to find the exact problect as code written are basic and corrrect.

Comment: This is why you need to check the error log.

Comment: i have updated the question with the log can you help me out with the issue coming. actually sails doesn't installed properly but empty project was running and when i do above changes then connection issue is coming. Is this possible that this issue might be coming due to improper sails installation?

Comment: You got either the ip address, port number, or connection method wrong, or the mysql server is not running.

Comment: Have You install Sails-mysql adapter?

Comment: yes. its working fine now thank you guys.!